# Prevent Ajax/Json to refresh page after succes

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, model-view-controller, file-upload

First i have now tried every page in here but nothing help. So this looks like all the others bus it isn't

i simply wants a file uploader where the image's are saved first and pass the image's ID back to a hidden input field as a string so i can find images again when the form is submitted.

no matter what i do i can't prevent the page for refreshing, which make the input field disappear  :(
here is my code

HTML

```
        <label for="file-uploader" class="custom-file-upload">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-5x"></i><br /> Custom Upload
        </label>
        <input style="display: none" id="file-uploader" name="file" multiple="" type="file" />
        <div id="input-wrapper">
            Here comes all input fields
        </div>
```

AJAX/JSON

```
        $("#file-uploader").change(function () {
            var formData = new FormData();
            var totalFiles = document.getElementById("file-uploader").files.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
                var file = document.getElementById("file-uploader").files[i];

                formData.append("file-uploader", file);
            }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Fileuploader", "Admin")',
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data, e) {
                        $('#input-wrapper').append($('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'imagesId').attr('value', data.Id));
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
            });
        return false;
        });
```

CONTROLLER

```
    public JsonResult Fileuploader(int? pictureId)
    {
        db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var name = "";
        if (pictureId != null)
        {
            var findImage = db.Imageses.Find(pictureId);
            if (findImage == null) return Json(new { result = "Error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            var filename = findImage.Url.Substring(10);
            var path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + filename);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(path);
            }
            db.Imageses.Remove(findImage);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[i];
                name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var fileformat = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                var filename = name + fileformat;
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), filename);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[i];
                var img = new Images()
                {
                    Filename = file.FileName,
                    DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                    Url = "~/Uploads/" + name
                };
                db.Imageses.Add(img);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return Json(new { result = "Sucess", Id=name }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend downloading fiddler to see what you're requesting and receiving

Comment: I have never tried, at this end, fiddler. but all the data is correct. for my point of view is it just about figuring out why it still refreshing after ajax.succes. But i will try fiddler right away :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your #file-uploader sitting inside a form with an action method on it?

I would try taking the action attribute off, then adding the attribute to the form element in the success function of your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I just disabled "enable Browser Sync" and it is working.